# Rough estimastes for roundtrip time in a client-server system

Tags: performance, architecture, client-server, n-tier-architecture

I want to know your rules of thumb regarding the roundtrip times for the different entities in a client-server environment. The timings are to bring an understanding of how expensive it is to make a request in different parts of the call chain. That is, get a feeling of the impact of a SELECT N+1 PROBLEM that may arise i the system. Assume we have the following entities

```
client <-> server <-> dbserver <-> disc access (on db server)
```

Assume

- the client is connected with the server over the internet
- server and dbserver is connected on the same switch
- the dbserver has a reasonable internal harddrive
- the client request is small and the same for the result from the server. Each in the rage of 1-4 KB.

The timings probably consists of sending data, processing on the other side, and returning new data.

My gut tells me that

client <-> server is 1-2 seconds

Server <-> dbserver 200 milliseconds

dbserver <-> harddrive 15-40 milliseconds

what are your experiences?

Comment: It's clearly a *how long is a piece of string?* question. Also, why on Earth would one want to *guess* rather than *measure*?

Comment: I want some general measures for at general discussion for newbie programmers to learn from.

Comment: Then don't give them facts to remember give them strategies to find this information for themselves.  Ping, tracert, code & db-query profiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Clinet ping to server ~100ms (round trip time)
- Client connection ~512KB/s UP ~1MB/s DOWN (cheap broadband/DSL)
- Server ping to DB ~1ms
- Server connection (to DB) ~10MB/s UP ~10MB/s DOWN (cheap LAN connection)
- DB hard drive "random" read/write ~2MB/s READ ~1MB/s WRITE (HDD)
- - But DB will likely be cached in RAM ~6GB/s bandwidth

Sending 4KB from client to server ~57ms ((4KB / 512KB/s) + 0.050s)
Processing time for server ~1ms
Sending 4KB from server to db ~1ms ((4KB / 10MB/s) + 0.001s)
Processing time for db ~1ms
RAM read for db ~1ms OR Hard Disk read for db ~2ms (4KB / 2MB/s)
Sending 4KB from db to server ~1ms
Sending 4KB from server to client ~54ms ((4KB / 1MB/s) + 0.050s)

**Total Round Trip ~117ms** (57ms+1ms+1ms+1ms+2ms+1ms+54ms)

---

The question is asinine on a lot of levels. Most IT professions wouldn't try to estimate a value that they can gain from a simple timed test. Different hardware will vary results greatly.

Comment: It is NOT estimation per see, rather it is to make newbies understand where an "N+1 SELECTION" occur, how it hurts performance depending on where it happens.. and that access to eg the DB can also cause problems when excessive requests are made to the db for a single response to the client.  I also am amazed how your harddrive is able to repond within a few ms's..